# Why isn't Typescript inferring this simple type in a conditional?

Tags: typescript

It infers the type here:

```js
let a: string | undefined;
let b = "";

if(typeof a === "string"){
  b = a
}
```

But it doesnt here:

```js
let a: string | undefined;
let b: string | undefined;
let c = ""
if(typeof a === "string" || typeof b === "string"){
  c= a || b
}
```

> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAhgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwgHwgVzQBMQAzdEQgbgChRIAjORVTHfI08q28CAYybJ0WALwQAROOooSACjABPAA4gA9iWgQR2ic2HicuRSvUR6WneL2ZxASgDe1CPzFRDZ6gF8gA)

What would be the correct way to write the code here ? Obviously, without unrolling the conditional.

Comment: If you break it into two separate conditionals, it seems to fix the error.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev see the last line of the post

Comment: It wasn't there when I hit Enter :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I added it probably at the same time than the comment, but I thought it'd be obvious tbh.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I wonder if chatgpt3 can solve it (apart from the answer which is correct.)

Comment: I checked, it suggests annotating `c` as `string` which doesn't work, evidently.

Comment: Nitpicking: if `a` and `b` are strings then `a || b` does not make sense. `||` is a [logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR). While traditionally it is used to mean _"`a` if `a` is not falsy, `b` otherwise)"_, TypeScript (and the modern JavaScript) provides the [null coalescing operator (`??`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, your code is incorrect and Typescript is correct. If `a` is the empty string and `b` is undefined, then the condition is true but `c` becomes `undefined`.

I would simply write it as follows:

```
let a: string | undefined;
let b: string | undefined;
const c = a ?? b ?? "";
```

Generally speaking Typescript does not work well with disjunctions of constraints, so better to avoid this kind of pattern.

Comment: Ah, empty strings being falsy values, this always gets me.

Comment: "and b is undefined" - then it wouldn't pass the `typeof b === "string"`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well, yes, but it would pass the first one and there is a `||` between them.

Comment: Ah, of course. I should go get a second coffee.

Answer (score 0):

If you pay attention on the code you see that `c` need to be `string` and your condition can assign to `c` the `undefined` type.

```js
let a: string | undefined;
let b: string | undefined;
let c: string | undefined = ""; // Now this var can be string or undefined

if(typeof a === "string" || typeof b === "string"){
    c = a || b
}
```